# How to use a dataframe in a PUT call in requests / aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, aiohttp

I'm trying to interact with an application through its API. According to the documentation I should be able to upload a custom "csv" file through a PUT call.

According to the documentation, a call should look like this:

```
PUT [URL]
Host: [host domain]
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 79182
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=c40cf424beg7650b

--c40cf424beg7650b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="my_csv.csv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

56.5770
32.5669
...
30.9038
20.4441
--c40cf424beg7650b--
```

The file should contain 8760 individual entries, which I currently have stored in a dataframe. I was wondering if someone knowns how I could pass this DataFrame in a aiohttp.ClientSession.put() call.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: is saving the df to csv (df.to_csv(<file_nmae>)) and sending the file a possibility?

Comment: @EzerK I'm not sure how to correctly do this. I tried to save it and then pass by assigning it `csv = open('my_csv.csv', 'rb')`. When I pass this I get an error that the object is not serialisable to JSON. `Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: Don't know, sorry

Comment: can you send the link to the api please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you have tried in terms of your code. But here is an example of uploading a file using aiohttp.

example:

```py
session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
url = '<api-url>'
files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

await session.put(url, data=files)
```

Comment: Yep that works perfectly, thank you so much! I tried to put the data through `session.put(url, json=files)` and got the serialisation error. Just as a small follow up question, do you know whether it is possible to transform a dataframe into the format that is read when using `open('report.csv, 'rb')`?

Comment: @Nesterion No worries. Please flag the question as answered by choosing this answer. And coming to your question, yes it is possible to read a dataframe in binary format although I don't recommend it for sending in a request as it is a python object.

Comment: Alright, I'll first save it as csv and load it back in again when I want to send it to the API. In that way my question is fully answered.

Answer (score 0):

A small update, I found a relatively easy way to avoid using buffered data. aiohttp has a build in FormData object that helped me out in this particular situation. This works with perfectly when passing columns in a Pandas DataFrame one by one as Pandas Series.

```
import aiohttp    

data = aiohttp.FormData()
data.add_field('file', relevant_data, filename=filename)
       
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    await session.put(url, data=data)
```